# Usage of Oxford comma in particular case

Tags: oxford-comma

In the sentence

> I had eggs, toast, and orange juice.

we're clearly speaking of three different items (eggs + toast + orange juice). My question is, if I don't use the oxford comma in that case

> I had eggs, toast and orange juice.

will I be speaking of only two items (eggs + toast with orange juice in it)?

Comment: This is not a case where an Oxford comma is either needed or appropriate. The last item in a list should always be preceded by a conjunction, usually "and". Some people even say that the commas in the list replace conjunctions so your sentence would have read "I had eggs and toast and orange juice". Your sentence contains a list of three single word items, the first and second separated by a comma and the last indicated by "and". If your breakfast had consisted of "...cereal and milk, sausage and bacon, and toast and marmalade" there  is a case for the Oxford but even there it's not essential.

Comment: @BoldBen "The Oxford comma is an optional comma before the word 'and' at the end of a list: We sell books, videos, and magazines. It's known as the Oxford comma because it was traditionally used by printers, readers, and editors at Oxford University Press. " - [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/explore/what-is-the-oxford-comma) (Oxford)

Comment: If you were speaking of [A] + [B + C], you would have two elements in your list (one composite). As you need an 'and' before your final list member, you would need 'A **and** B & C', 'eggs and toast & orange'. Unlikely here.

Comment: Oxford takes a capital o. What is it with people? English is SO easy with caps: Languages and proper names take a capital letter.

Comment: That should be "_toast with orange juice **on** it_".  Which sounds disgusting anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Oxford comma is *an option*. It is said to be helpful in situations where ambiguity is possible, e.g.

> I love my parents, Donald Trump and Deputy Dawg.

An unworldly reader (or a Martian, or an AI) might possibly suppose that I meant to write that those are my parents. However, grammarians dislike ambiguity, and we can probably imagine examples where common sense does not immediately resolve any initial ambiguity of meaning. I would think that in the context of breakfast, "toast and orange juice" would resolve in a reader's mind into "some toast on a plate" and "orange juice in a glass", and not some composite edible/drinkable soggy mess. When speaking aloud, there are no commas, Oxford, or otherwise, and you would surely not expect a listener to be confused.

If you are writing for publication, you should probably be using a style guide. Here is a list of some common style guides you could use while writing:

> Associated Press Style (AP) does not use the Oxford comma.
> American Psychological Association Style (APA) does use the Oxford comma.
> Chicago Manual of Style (CMS) does use the Oxford comma.
> The Modern Languages Association (MLA) does use the Oxford comma.
> The Oxford University Press (OUP) does use the Oxford comma.

Comment: 'When speaking aloud, there are no commas, Oxford, or otherwise, and you would surely not expect a listener to be confused.' Yes, in this case. But there _are_ modulations and pauses in spoken English, which are used to disambiguate. The comma is often an attempt to reproduce the disambiguating (/ formatting / pause-for-effect ...) device. The best advice about using the Oxford comma has already been given here on ELU. The answerer gave one example where its use disambiguated, and one where its use actually _introduced_ ambiguity. The best advice is _read that answer, not a style guide_.

Comment: I normally delete answers on here that get a downvote, but I can't in this case, because it has been accepted. I shall have to wait and see what _vox populis_ says.

Comment: There **must** be three list items in 'I had A, B[,] and C'. The question does not bear scrutiny. Only when another 'and' is included after A does ambiguity such as OP suggests possibly arise.